# Ajuda com shell script e expressões regulares

Tags: shell-script

Estou fazendo esse código shell script que deve passar por cada linha de um arquivo texto, e determinar se a sentença é positiva ou negativa conforme a condição do IF

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
file="${1}"

while read line;do

        pos=$(grep -oP ':\)|;\)|:D' $file | wc -l)   
        neg=$(grep -oP ':\('        $file | wc -l) 

if (( $pos * 2 > $neg * 5 )) ;then
   echo "Sentença Positiva "
else
   echo "Sentença Negativa"
fi

sleep 1
done <"$file"
```

Mas quanto eu executo o script encima desse arquivo de texto: teste.txt

```
teste:) teste :) teste :) teste :)
teste:( teste :( teste :( teste :(
```

Em vez dele retornar:

```
Sentença Positiva
Sentença Negativa
```

ele retorna as duas negativas:

```
Sentença Negativa
Sentença Negativa
```

Como eu corrijo esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Você está iterando o arquivo linha a linha com o `while read line;do`, mas está aplicando o `grep` no arquivo inteiro. A seguinte modificação deve corrigir este problema:

```
pos=$(echo "$line" | grep -oP ':\)|;\)|:D' | wc -l)
neg=$(echo "$line" | grep -oP ':\('        | wc -l)
```